# s3.putObject returns 400 bad request error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a code to upload images to s3 bucket , I am able to do it successfully using aws s3 javascript sdk. But I am getting a PUT request 400 bad request error in the developer tools console. My code

```
function upload()
{
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId:"accesskey",
        secretAccessKey:"secretaccesskey"
)};
   s3 =new AWS.S3();

   var params = {
       Bucket:'mybucketname',
       Key:'myimagename',
       Body:<file object>,
       ACL:'public-read'
   }
   s3.putObject(params,function(err,res){
       if(err)
         console.log(err);
       else
         {
            console.log('success');
         }
   }); 
}
```

I tried to print res object in my console, it is empty.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can check if the provided access_key and secret_key user has permissions to upload the file to s3 manually.

If you are able to upload, then goto S3 bucket, then click on your bucket and click on permission, and then check on CORS configuration.

It should be something similar to below.

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

You can also change the origin to your url based on your requirement.